# How to sum variables in VBA to check input data is correct?

Tags: vba, variables, addition, calculation

May seem like a stupid question, but how do you sum variables in VBA to check input data is correct?

I'm trying to check the user has inputted data correctly into a UserForm before they continue to the next page. To do this I want to sum some of their input variables. If they don't input it correctly, they get a message box telling them to revise the numbers. My code is:

```
Dim BinQnt As Double
Dim FillQnt As Double
Dim FineQnt As Double
Dim CoarQnt As Double
Dim RAPQnt As Double
Dim CRQnt As Double

    If BinQnt + FillQnt + FineQnt + CoarQnt + RAPQnt + CRQnt = 100 Then
    'Code here for inserting values into database. Omitted to save space and confusion.
    Else
        MsgBox "Error, please check mixture design sums to 100%."
    End If
```

When I'm testing it, it always goes to the error message box and I'm not sure why. Very sure I am adding variables which sum to 100 (haha). I first tried it without defining the variables, and now I have it still doesn't work.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: _"Very sure I am adding variables which sum to 100 (haha)"_. In programming you **never** rely on "being sure", but instead you **verify** your assumption(s). There's many ways to do this, here's one: put the line `Debug.Print BinQnt + FillQnt + FineQnt + CoarQnt + RAPQnt + CRQnt` just before the `If ...` line and observe the output in the Debug window.

Comment: Many thanks for your rapid response! Ok, I have run the test and the output is zero. Not sure why this is. Any ideas?

Comment: I must ask if you are giving these variables a value at some point? Not sure how much of the code is missing, but in this example, you are defining them, but not giving them a value. But yes, Debug.Print is a good option. If you step through the code (F8) you can also look at the value of a variable by hovering it, or by looking in the Locals Window.

Comment: One way would be setting a variable to the total, like: `tot = BinQnt + FillQnt + FineQnt + CoarQnt + RAPQnt + CRQnt` and then change the message to include it: `MsgBox "Error, please check mixture design sums to 100%. Currently at :" & tot & "%"` so that the user is aware of the current number. If that's desirable.

Comment: Many thanks Christofer. I have added your kind recommendation. Through this test, the output is still zero. And if I try and add the variable name .value, it comes out with a compile error: invalid qualifier?

Comment: A "Double" variable doesn't have a .value property. The variable only contains the value so when reffering to the variable name, you get the value. But where does e.g. `BinQnt` get its value from? I'm guessing from a worksheet or userform, and doesn't seem to be referenced propely, since yo uare getting zero.

Comment: 'BinQnt' is a variable obtained from filling in a Text Box in the UserForm. Thank you for the clarification for the "Double"! I have now got it working! I will post below the reason for solution.

Is there a way I can give you kudos for your help?

Answer (score 0):

**Do you want to round it or not?**

In your question, you have the variables as Doubles, and in the answer as integers. Having them as integers will make it easier to hit 100%, but it will round to the nearest integer `(2,4 = 2 | 2,6 = 3)`

I will assume you are using all texboxes in the form, and as such use this code that is universal:

```
Dim tot As Double
tot = 0
For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" And IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
        tot = tot + c.Value
    End If
Next c
If tot = 100 Then
    'Code here for inserting values into database. Omitted to save space and confusion.
Else
    MsgBox "Error, please check mixture design sums to 100%. Currently at " & tot & "%."
End If
```

This would give us something like this:
[image]

However, using Integer or Long, gives us this:
[image]

Also, the reason as to why I'm using `IsNumeric(c.Value)`, is to stop the code from failing in case of empty boxes (or filled with invalid entries).
You could also place a check here in case no boxes are allowed to be empty.

Comment: Thanks Christofer for your continued assistance and patience. I would like them as numbers with 2 decimal places ideally. I've tried the code you have kindly provided, but I get a runtime error. Kind of new to this, but now it's clicked that textbox output is a string, is there no way to format the textboxes' outputs to be only numbers, so that when I click on next it can just sum the numbers, and check if = 100??

Comment: What error and where? In my code I use `IsNumeric(c.Value)` to only accept numbers, and then add these to a numbers only variable (Double). You can round any variable to 2 decimals by using `Round(variableName, 2)` So it's up to you if you want to `Round(c.value, 2)` or `Round(tot, 2)` at the `If`, depending on how many times you want to round it. For the second option you'd need to round the message as well.

Comment: This code is run from within the Userform, otherwise you'd need to replace `Me` with the name of the userform.